# Append a Lists Contents to another List C#

Tags: c#

I have the following:

1. A main List called GlobalStrings
2. Another List called localStrings

In a loop for example:

```
List<string> GlobalStrings = new List<string>(); 
List<string> localStrings = new List<string>();
for(x=1;x<10;x++)
{
    localStrings.Add("some value"); 
    localStrings.Add("some value");
}
// Want to append localStrings to GlobalStrings as easily as possible
```

Comment: stack over flow always rocks...nice question...

Comment: You are doing it wrong, `localStrings = new List<string>;` should be placed before the `for` loop

Comment: Wassim, I think that's why he differentiates between local and global; localStrings is local to the for-loop scope, GlobalStrings is in the global scope.

Comment: This is a poor example (that invites totally wrongheaded comments like Wassim's), since obviously you could just `Add` to `GlobalStrings` instead of to `localStrings`. And FWIW you loop only runs 9 times. Better would be `for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {var localStrings = GetAListOfStrings(); /* append those to GlobalStrings */}`

Comment: 11 years later...

Answer (score 338, accepted):

```
GlobalStrings.AddRange(localStrings);
```

Note: You cannot declare the list object using the interface (IList).
Documentation: [`List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange).

Answer (score 63):

```
GlobalStrings.AddRange(localStrings);
```

That works.

Documentation: [`List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange).

Comment: While correct, this answer now stands as a duplicate of Lee's answer.

Answer (score 23):

Try AddRange-method:

```
GlobalStrings.AddRange(localStrings);
```

Comment: While correct, this answer now stands as a duplicate of Lee's answer.

Answer (score 8):

With Linq

```
var newList = GlobalStrings.Append(localStrings)
```

Comment: Append doesn't seem to exist? Do you have a link to MSDN doc for it?

Comment: Perhaps you meant Concat ... though that would mean a lot of copying, and is a good illustration of how *not* to use LINQ.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my example:

```
    private List<int> m_machinePorts = new List<int>();

    public List<int> machinePorts
    {
        get { return m_machinePorts; }
    }

    Init()
    {
        // Custom function to get available ethernet ports
        List<int> localEnetPorts = _Globals.GetAvailableEthernetPorts();

        // Custome function to get available serial ports
        List<int> localPorts = _Globals.GetAvailableSerialPorts();

        // Build Available port list 
        m_machinePorts.AddRange(localEnetPorts);
        m_machinePorts.AddRange(localPorts);
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get "terse" :)

```
List<string>GlobalStrings = new List<string>(); 

for(int x=1; x<10; x++) GlobalStrings.AddRange(new List<string> { "some value", "another value"});
```