# Adding List<t>.add() another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an `IEnumerable<TravelDetails>` and I am trying to add the vales in the `for`-loop to a `List<TravelDetails>`. I keep getting the errors.

> Error  15  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'TrafficCore.DataObjects.TripDetails' C:\TrafficNew\TI 511-Web\Traffic 2.0\511Traffic\511Traffic\Models\DrivingTime.cs

My code is

```
List<TripDetails> tripDetailsCollection = new List<TripDetails>();
foreach (DrivingTimeRoute dtr in dtRoutes)
{
    foreach (Trip trip in dtr.Trips)
    {
        foreach (TripPathLink tpl in trip.TripPathLinks)
        {
            tplCollection.Add(tpl);
        }
        IEnumerable<TripDetails> tripDetails = //long Linq-to-Sql here
        List<TripDetails> td = tripDetails.ToList();
        tripDetailsCollection.Add(td); // <<< Error here
    }
}
```

Can some one help me with this.
Thanks,
Pawan

Comment: Can you tell what line is the error on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append a Lists Contents to another List C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825568/append-a-lists-contents-to-another-list-c-sharp)

Answer (score 339, accepted):

[`List<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) adds a single element.  Instead, use [`List<T>.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) to add multiple values.

Additionally, `List<T>.AddRange` takes an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you don't need to convert `tripDetails` into a `List<TripDetails>`, you can pass it directly, e.g.:

```
tripDetailsCollection.AddRange(tripDetails);
```