# How to unite two List<T> and assign result to the third List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 3 List<> objects.

```
List<T> listA = new List<t>();
List<T> listB = new List<t>();
List<T> listC = new List<t>();
```

I need to unite listA and ListB and assign it to ListC:

```
List<T> listC = new ListA +ListB;
```

My question is how to implement it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1825577/1689451

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    List<int> A = new List<int>();
    A.Add(1);
    A.Add(2);
    List<int> B = new List<int>();
    B.Add(3);
    B.Add(4);

    List<int> C = new List<int>();

    C = A.Union<int>(B).ToList<int>();
```

Comment: It wasn't specified, but `Union` would remove duplicate entries if they exist. If @Michael wants to keep duplicates, use `Concat` instead.

Comment: You should have mentioned that OP needs to implement an `EqualityComparer<T>`(like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12873969/284240)) if it's a custom type. Otherwise he would compare reference types by reference instead by equality.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx):

```
List<T> listA = new List<t>();
List<T> listB = new List<t>();
List<T> listC = new List<t>();

listC.AddRange(listA);
listC.AddRange(listB);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `AddRange()` this:-

```
    listC.AddRange(listA);
    listC.AddRange(listB);
```

Answer (score 3):

Kinda depends on your requirements, but might be as easy as

```
listC.AddRange(listA);
listC.AddRange(listB);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
listC.AddRange(listA);
listC.AddRange(listB);
```

Answer (score 2):

Either use `AddRange` as others have already mentioned or , if you want to union both as mentioned, you need to provide a `IEqualityComparer<T>` and use [`Enumerable.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx):

```
List<Foo> third = first.Union(second, new FooComparer()).ToList();
```

Here's an examplary implementation:

```
public class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id; // assuming that there's a value type like ID as key
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Union returns only unique values.