# Insert list of int to another existing list as appmetadata?

Tags: c#, list, auth0

I am working with Auth0 where i need to update appmetadata .

this is how my app meta data looks like

```
userUpdateRequest.AppMetadata = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
{
 {"toysNumber",new List<int> {2,3,9,77} }
};
```

I have a list of int that contains some more toys number.

```
List<int> itemsToAddInMetadata = new list<int>{22,33,65,..}.
```

I want to do something like that -

```
userUpdateRequest.AppMetadata = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
{
 {"toysNumber",new List<int> {2,3,9,77,itemsToAddInMetadata} }
};
```

I cant figure out the correct syntax. how can i insert list of int in another list like for loop ?
[NB: in my case the issue was proper syntax]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append a Lists Contents to another List C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825568/append-a-lists-contents-to-another-list-c-sharp)

Comment: use AddRange method of List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two lists first:

```
List<int> itemsToAddInMetadata = new List<int>{22, 33, 65};
List<int> itemsToAddInMetadata1 = new List<int> { 22, 33, 65 };
itemsToAddInMetadata1.AddRange(itemsToAddInMetadata);
```

Then add the whole list to your dictionary:

```
userUpdateRequest.AppMetadata = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
{
 {"toysNumber",itemsToAddInMetadata1}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add the numbers via the constructor of the `new List<int>`

```
   var itemsToAddInMetadata = new List<int> { 22, 33, 65 };

   userUpdateRequest.AppMetadata = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
   {
      { "toysNumber", new List<int>(itemsToAddInMetadata) { 2, 3, 9, 7 } }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
userUpdateRequest.AppMetadata["toysNumber"].AddRange(new[] {22, 33, 65, ...})
```