# Problem to use a list instead of an array

Tags: c#, list, listbox, openfiledialog

here i am trying to do a music media player. I do it great thanks a normal array. However when i am trying to use a list impossible to do it.

```
stringName.Add(openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames);
```

the first problem is in this line, I can't convert a string array to string. so i can use the other method without it but it give me only one sound from my list impossible to get more. And I need to load more songs.

Here my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //--------------------Thanks to array work perfectly
                //arraylist1 = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
                //a2 = openFileDialog1.FileNames;

                //for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.Length; i++)
                //{
                //    listBox1.Items.Add(arraylist1[i]);
                //}

                
                //----------------------- with lists it doesn't work-------------------------
                stringName.Add(openFileDialog1.SafeFileName);
                
                MessageBox.Show(stringName.Count.ToString());

                for (int i = 0; i < stringName.Count; i++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(stringName[i]);
                }
               
            }

        }
```

the goal here is to put my list of name songs instead my list and show this list in my listbox1.
Do you have any Idea ? I am new in c# i want to improve my code for a better understanding and upgrade. Thank you very much for your help. Or maybe its the only solution ?

Comment: `stringName.AddRange(openFileDialog1.SafeFileName)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append a Lists Contents to another List C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825568/append-a-lists-contents-to-another-list-c-sharp)

Comment: it told me impossible to convert a string into a generic ienumerable collection with AddRange

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was assuming the type was a List. Can you include the types of the variables/members in your code (i.e. `stringName` and `openFileDialog1.SafeFileName`)?

Comment: **`ArrayList != List<T>`**

Comment: I finally found the solution i will post it tomorrow